# AngularJs: Error: Custom filter for pairing items throw error: "10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create custom filter which will transform array to new array with pairs of items (I need this filter just to show items in two columns):

**Input: [item1,item2,item3,item4, etc...]**

**Result: [[item1, item2], [item3,item3], etc...]**

I've found that any implementation of such finctionality throws **Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!**

Even simple return doesn't work:

```
function pair() {
    return function (items) {
        return [[items[0], items[1]], [items[2], items[3]]];
    };
}
```

M.b. there is another way how to split collection intro columns?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dmitry_zaets/Lae2hxr6/1/

Comment: You need to show the actual code you're using (full filter definition and use).

Comment: @hon2a Sorry for that, updated link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **CANNOT** use the filter method to modify the data structure.   Modifying the data creates an endless cycle, where each modification to the data causes the `$digest` to queue another `$watch()`, which in turn queues another call to the filter, which causes another data modification, ad nauseam.  The error you are receiving is Angular's way of saying that this could go on forever, so it stops it from happening.  A filter should only ever be used to restrict visibility of items in an array, never modify.

If you need the data represented in a different form, it should be handled earlier.

Also, your fiddle isn't correctly showing your sample code.

Answer (score 0):

A filter must not generate a new array every time it is called (see [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d)%7Bvar%20e%3Da(c,d);return%20b(e,c,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:16,%22oldVal%22:14%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d)%7Bvar%20e%3Da(c,d);return%20b(e,c,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:18,%22oldVal%22:16%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d)%7Bvar%20e%3Da(c,d);return%20b(e,c,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:20,%22oldVal%22:18%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d)%7Bvar%20e%3Da(c,d);return%20b(e,c,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:22,%22oldVal%22:20%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d)%7Bvar%20e%3Da(c,d);return%20b(e,c,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:24,%22oldVal%22:22%7D%5D%5D)). If you really need to create columns on the data level, you need to create (and keep) a modified data structure. If you just need to create columns in the view, there are other ways to do it (like [fluid grid layouts](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html)).